# Como e onde criar arquivos no Android com Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Em meu aplicativo em Delphi estou criando um arquivo texto simples no Android, usando o seguinte código:

```
var lst: TStringList;
begin
   lst := TStringList.Create;
   lst.Clear;
   lst.Add('a');
   lst.Add('b');
   lst.Add('c');
   lst.Add('d');

   // Esse path é: /data/data/com.embarcadero.MyApp/files/test.txt
   if not TFile.Exists(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath,'test.txt')) then      
       lst.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath,'test.txt'));
```

E eu vejo por meio do Debug que o arquivo é criado. Quando executo pela segunda vez a rotina o `if not TFile.Exists` também detecta que o arquivo já existe.

PROBLEMAS:

1) Quando tento encontrar o arquivo `test.txt` no Android, sequer eu encontro esse diretório "/data/data/...";

2) Não sei é possível no Android, mas gostaria de salvar esse arquivo na mesma pasta de instalação do programa. Em projetos com a VCL do Delphi eu usava como referência o caminho do executável `Application.ExeName`, que em Android não é compatível. É possível/indicado fazer isso no Android?

Comment: O problema é que as versões novas do Android não permite você acessar algumas pastas

Answer (score 0):

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      TextFile: TStringList;
      FileName: string;
    begin

      try
        TextFile := TStringList.Create;
        try
    {$IFDEF ANDROID}// if the operative system is Android
          FileName := Format('%smyFile.txt', [GetHomePath]);
    {$ENDIF ANDROID}
    {$IFDEF WIN32}
          FileName := Format('%smyFile.txt', [ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))]);
    {$ENDIF WIN32}
          if FileExists(FileName) then
          begin
            TextFile.LoadFromFile(FileName); // load the file in TStringList
            ShowMessage(TextFile.Text); // there is the text
          end
          else
          begin
            ShowMessage('File not exists, Create New File');

            TextFile.Text := 'There is a new File (Here the contents)';
            TextFile.SaveToFile(FileName); // create a new file from a TStringList

          end;
        finally
          TextFile.Free;
        end;
      except
        on E: Exception do
          ShowMessage('ClassError: ' + E.ClassName + #13#13 + 'Message: ' +
              E.Message);
      end;
    end;
```

Créditos ao Angelim, por base na resposta [deste link](https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/diretorio-fixo-no-android-com-delphi-xe5/461695)

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, porém o problema não é criar o arquivo e sim 1) Localizar o arquivo que criei e, 2) Criar o arquivo em uma pasta específica, caso seja viável, tal como a pasta de instalação do aplicativo. Você sabe sobre essas informações?

Comment: Desculpa se pareceu um pouco confuso, mas ao salvar o arquivo acima, ele utiliza a função GetHomePath quando o ambiente é Android, talvez para buscar o arquivo criado, a mesma função seja útil. De qualquer forma, não consegui simular aqui (ambiente não ajudou). Chegando em casa, posto aqui.

Comment: Olá Lucas. Acho que não ficaram claras minhas dúvidas: Na primeira, imagine que você criou um arquivo TXT com seu aplicativo... agora imagine que você vá "na mão" em seu sistema de arquivos e diretórios do Android e queira encontrar esse arquivo que seu aplicativo criou, OK? Eu não estou encontrando, apesar de saber que o tal arquivo TXT foi criado com sucesso pelo meu aplicativo. Na segunda dúvida, eu quero escolher uma pasta específica para salvar o arquivo, tal como a pasta de instalação do aplicativo. Mas não sei se fazer isso e nem sei se é adequado/viável.